What does "you " in "you do" refer to?
At Orgocorp, Star-Lord is speaking to Ura, who, under the threat of Gamora’s gun,
managed to acquire the 89P13 patent, which is required to save Rocket:

Star-Lord: I'm so sorry about this, Ura.
Gamora: Oh, please.
Star-Lord: We're here to save the life of our friend, that is all. We
paid her to help us get in and get out. You'd think that'd mean,  "Oh,
I'm gonna help you do it in a way that no one knows it's
happening.” But no, what she means is, "I'm gonna shoot people.
"Threaten people's lives."
Gamora: Shut up!

What does "you " in "you do" refer to?

Peter is referring to himself and the Guardians in the third person, as if he's talking to a hypothetical listener. When he says "You", he actually means himself. You could rewrite the sentence as;

We're here to save the life of our friend, that is all. We paid her to
help us get in and get out. I thought that meant "I'm going
help you, Peter, do it in a way that no one knows it's happening."

Obviously it's more emphatic and funny if he (sarcastically) pretends that he's trying to explain this ridiculous situation to a disinterested bystander.
